# NodeJS - Promise returns undefined object inside a redis pool await

Tags: node.js, redis, promise

I have a Redis pool object created from `redis-connection-pool`. It looks for a key to obtain an array of all image identifiers. Then, for every element, another Redis key is looked up so that, the values are appended into a one JSON object. This object is returned as a response to a `GET` request.

For some odd reason (perhaps, Redis error?), while the Promise is resolved with correct data, the function consuming this Promise always sees an `undefined` object.

**Original attempt**

```
async function allImageData() {
    var configPool = redisPools.configPool;
    var resp = {};
    var images = [];
    var imageDetails = {};
    //
    await configPool.get('allImages', async (err, reply) => {
        if (err) {
            resp = {
                'data': {}
            }
            reject(resp)
        } else {
            if (reply === null) {
                resp = {
                    'data': {}
                }
                reject(resp)
            } else {
                imageDetails = JSON.parse(reply)
                images = imageDetails['allImages']
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    imageDetailsCache(images).then(function (result) {
                        resp = {
                            'data': result
                        }
                        resolve(resp) //Correct data; but, received as undefined
                    }).catch(function (result) {
                        resp = {
                            'data': {}
                        }
                        reject(resp)
                    })
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Next attempt**

The Promise is returned after the Redis `get` is over.

```
async function allMachineData() {
    var configPool = redisPools.configPool;
    var resp = {};
    var images = [];
    var imageDetails = {};
    //
    await configPool.get('allImages', async (err, reply) => {
        if (err) {
            resp = {
                'data': {}
            }
            reject(resp)
        } else {
            if (reply === null) {
                resp = {
                    'data': {}
                }
                reject(resp)
            } else {
                imageDetails = JSON.parse(reply)
                images = imageDetails['allImages']
            }
        }
    })
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // images array is empty; so, received as empty object
        imageDetailsCache(images).then(function (result) {
            resp = {
                'data': result
            }
            resolve(resp)
        }).catch(function (result) {
            resp = {
                'data': {}
            }
            reject(resp)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: please note that `.get()` is using the **callback** mechanism and it does **not** return `Promise`, `await` on a constant or void has no effect.

Comment: But I am returning a Promise in the callback. How about the second attempt?

Comment: you're doing the same thing with `.get` in both attempts

Comment: To check if `get` returns a promise ... try adding `await configPool.get( .....).then(result => result)` if you don't get an error, then get returns a promise, if you do get an error then you'll understand Neverever's comment a little better

Comment: you also use `reject(resp)` inside the get callback ... what is this `reject` function?

Comment: `Correct data; but, received as undefined` - received where? `allImageData` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your attempts you use

```
await configPool.get('allImages', async (err, reply) => {
```

firstly, `.get` doesn't return a promise, so `await`ing it makes no sense
secondly, you're not using await inside the callback, so no need to make it `async`

Seems your code can be simplified

First, since you want to return a Promise, wrap `configPool.get` in a promise, which will be resolved/rejected in the callback

after that, it's just a matter of promise chaining, since your code implies that `imageDetailsCache` returns a promise, it's easy as:

```
function allImageData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        redisPools.configPool.get('allImages', (err, reply) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(reply));
    })
    .then(reply => {
        if (reply === null) return Promise.reject(null);
        const imageDetails = JSON.parse(reply);
        return imageDetailsCache(imageDetails.allImages);
    })
    .then(data => ({data}))
    .catch(() => Promise.reject({data:{}}));
}
```

Comment: This solution worked - thanks! If you won't mind, can you please explain the `then(data => ({data}))` syntax? I was trying `then(function (result) {Promise.resolve(result)})` - it showed weird errors.

Comment: `data => ({data})` === `function(data) { return {data:data};}`

Comment: Where do I place a `.catch()` if `configPool.get` did a `reject(err)`?

Comment: `.catch(() => Promise.reject({data:{}}));` catches all rejections - and behaves like your code would